# Triggering some event when a route is dragged (i.e. new waypoint) in Google Maps JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Basically I want to be able to extract latitude and longitude information about the start, destination, and any waypoints in between on the route from a Google Maps view.

At the moment I'm working from this example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions

While testing this out, I'm just storing the info I need in a variable called 'route' in the global scope.

```
var saveRoute = function (directionsDisplay) {
    var final_waypoints=[], waypoints;
    var route_legs = directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0];
    if(!route_legs) {
      return
    }
    route.start = {'lat': route_legs.start_location.lat(), 'lng': route_legs.start_location.lng()}
    route.end = {'lat': route_legs.end_location.lat(), 'lng': route_legs.end_location.lng()}
    var waypoints = route_legs.via_waypoints 

    for(var i=0;i<waypoints.length;i++) {
      final_waypoints[i] = [waypoints[i].lat(), waypoints[i].lng()] 
    }
    route.waypoints = final_waypoints;
}
```

I'm able to get the information I need initially by including a call to my own function in the 'setupPlaceChangedListener', which reads the information from the DirectionsRenderer object and saves it in a variable. However, I want to allow users to drag the route shown, allowing them to make a change to the exact route taken (not the start and destination necessarily).

Initially I was hoping I could trigger some event to re-run my function any time a change occurs. The 'dragend' function only works when the map is being dragged, and only do anything if the drag includes a new waypoint.

Is there any way to do this? Am I misusing Google Maps API this way? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [Draggable Directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DraggableDirections):

> Because draggable directions are modified and rendered client-side, you may wish to monitor and handle the directions_changed event on the DirectionsRenderer to be notified when the user has modified the displayed directions.